# How can i find the direction of HTML5 range input using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to find real time if the range slider is moved left or right using jquery.
Thanks
following is my current implementation.

```
$("#zoom-slider").on("input", function(e) {
var curr_val = $("#zoom-slider").val();
if( curr_val > zoom_slider )
{
   console.log( " +ive : right" );
}else
{
   console.log( " -ive : left" );
}
zoom_slider = curr_val;
});
```

But i was asking if there is any event.

Comment: After your edit, your current implementation is fine.

Answer (score 6):

Using the `input` event alongside storing the previous value for comparison should do what you need:

```js
var oldVal;
$("input").on("input", function() {
    var newVal = $(this).val();
    if(newVal > oldVal) {
        $("div").text("right");
    }
    else if(newVal < oldVal) {
        $("div").text("left");
    }
    oldVal = newVal;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="range">
<div></div>
```