# Range slider next and prev values always going to next value when moving

Tags: javascript, html, css

I write a code for range slider with some specific range values
`[1000,2000,3000,4000,5000,6000,7000,8000,9000,10000,11000,12000,13000,14000,15000,16000,17000,18000,19000,20000,21000,22000,23000,24000, 25000,30000,35000,40000,45000, 50000, 60000,70000, 80000, 90000, 100000]`

but when I move the slider curser in-between `4000-5000` for example `4320` it always goes to `5000` in-fact I want to move it on `4000` when moving slider to backword.

Also *background-color* behaving weirdly due to slider jumps.

this is how my JS looks like:

```
const slider = document.getElementById("myinput")
const min = parseInt(slider.min)
const max = parseInt(slider.max)
const value = parseInt(slider.value)

slider.style.background = `linear-gradient(to right, #0080FF 0%, #0080FF ${(value-min)/(max-min)*100}%, #596680 ${(value-min)/(max-min)*100}%, #596680 100%)`

slider.oninput = function() {
  this.style.background = `linear-gradient(to right, #0080FF 0%, #0080FF ${(this.value-this.min)/(this.max-this.min)*100}%, #596680 ${(this.value-this.min)/(this.max-this.min)*100}%, #596680 100%)`
};

//

var arr = [1000,2000,3000,4000,5000,6000,7000,8000,9000,10000,11000,12000,13000,14000,15000,16000,17000,18000,19000,20000,21000,22000,23000,24000, 25000,30000,35000,40000,45000, 50000, 60000,70000, 80000, 90000, 100000];
var ele = document.querySelector('.slider')
ele.setAttribute('step', arr[0]);
var i = 0;

function a() {
  ele.removeAttribute('step')
  var value = ele.value
  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] > value) {
      ele.value = arr[i]
      break;
    }
  }
  document.querySelector('span').innerHTML = ele.value
}

//

// Add a change event listener to the range slider
slider.addEventListener('change', function() {
  // Get the value of the range slider
  var value = parseInt(this.value);
  var container = document.querySelector('#rangeValue');

  let cost;
  if (value === 1000) {
    cost = 0.0350;
  } else if (value > 1000 && value <= 2000) {
    cost = 0.0340;
  } else if (value > 2000 && value <= 3000) {
    cost = 0.0329;
  } else if (value > 3000 && value <= 4000) {
    cost = 0.0319;
  } else if (value > 4000 && value <= 5000) {
    cost = 0.031;
  } else if (value > 5000 && value <= 6000) {
    cost = 0.0301;
  } else if (value > 6000 && value <= 7000) {
    cost = 0.0292;
  } else if (value > 7000 && value <= 8000) {
    cost = 0.0283;
  } else if (value > 8000 && value <= 9000) {
    cost = 0.0274;
  } else if (value > 9000 && value <= 10000) {
    cost = 0.0266;
  } else if (value > 10000 && value <= 11000) {
    cost = 0.0258;
  } else if (value > 11000 && value <= 12000) {
    cost = 0.025;
  } else if (value > 12000 && value <= 13000) {
    cost = 0.0243;
  } else if (value > 13000 && value <= 14000) {
    cost = 0.0236;
  } else if (value > 14000 && value <= 15000) {
    cost = 0.0228;
  } else if (value > 15000 && value <= 16000) {
    cost = 0.0222;
  } else if (value > 16000 && value <= 17000) {
    cost = 0.0215;
  } else if (value > 17000 && value <= 18000) {
    cost = 0.0209;
  } else if (value > 18000 && value <= 19000) {
    cost = 0.0202;
  } else if (value > 19000 && value <= 20000) {
    cost = 0.0196;
  } else if (value > 20000 && value <= 21000) {
    cost = 0.019;
  } else if (value > 21000 && value <= 22000) {
    cost = 0.0185;
  } else if (value > 22000 && value <= 23000) {
    cost = 0.0179;
  } else if (value > 23000 && value <= 24000) {
    cost = 0.0174;
  } else if (value > 24000 && value <= 25000) {
    cost = 0.0168;
  } else if (value > 25000 && value <= 30000) {
    cost = 0.0163;
  } else if (value > 30000 && value <= 35000) {
    cost = 0.0159;
  } else if (value > 35000 && value <= 40000) {
    cost = 0.0154;
  } else if (value > 40000 && value <= 45000) {
    cost = 0.0149;
  } else if (value > 45000 && value <= 50000) { //check
    cost = 0.0145;
  } else if (value > 50000 && value <= 60000) {
    cost = 0.014;
  } else if (value > 60000 && value <= 70000) {
    cost = 0.0136;
  } else if (value > 70000 && value <= 80000) {
    cost = 0.0132;
  } else if (value > 80000 && value <= 90000) {
    cost = 0.0128;
  } else if (value > 90000 && value <= 100000) {
    cost = 0.0124;
  }

  var totval = value * cost;
  totval = totval.toFixed(2);

  container.innerHTML = totval;
  // Print the value to the console
  // console.log(value);
});

const
  range = document.getElementById('myinput'),
  rangeV = document.getElementById('rangeV'),
  setValue = () => {
    const
      newValue = Number((range.value - range.min) * 100 / (range.max - range.min)),
      newPosition = 10 - (newValue * 0.2);
    rangeV.innerHTML = `<span>${range.value}</span>`;
    rangeV.style.left = `calc(${newValue}% + (${newPosition}px))`;
  };
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", setValue);
range.addEventListener('input', setValue);
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/talha0032/5hq7vpx6/74/) of all the code

Comment: it's because of using step function a() is increasing value forward so it's showing 5000

Comment: So you'll need to figure out which direction the slider is getting dragged in first of all, https://stackoverflow.com/q/31849122/1427878

Comment: yes you are right, but when I am decreasing values from `5000` to `4000` e.g `4300` it still jump to `5000` in-fact I wanna move to `4000`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem.

This code will set the value of the slider to the nearest value in the array when the user moves the slider. It will also maintain the slider value when moving backward.

It also removes the unnecessary variable assignments and the for loop that was causing the background color to jump.

```
const slider = document.getElementById("myinput");
slider.oninput = function() {
  this.style.background = `linear-gradient(to right, #0080FF 0%, #0080FF ${(this.value-this.min)/(this.max-this.min)*100}%, #596680 ${(this.value-this.min)/(this.max-this.min)*100}%, #596680 100%)`;
};

// Add a change event listener to the range slider
slider.addEventListener('change', function() {

  // Get the value of the range slider
  var value = parseInt(this.value);
  var container = document.querySelector('#rangeValue');

  // Set the value of the slider to the nearest value in the array
  var arr = [1000,2000,3000,4000,5000,6000,7000,8000,9000,10000,11000,12000,13000,14000,15000,16000,17000,18000,19000,20000,21000,22000,23000,24000, 25000,30000,35000,40000,45000, 50000, 60000,70000, 80000, 90000, 100000];
  var nearest = arr.reduce(function (prev, curr) {
    return (Math.abs(curr - value) < Math.abs(prev - value) ? curr : prev);
  });
  if (value < nearest) {
    nearest = arr[arr.indexOf(nearest) - 1];
  }
  this.value = nearest;

  // display the value on the slider
  document.querySelector('span').innerHTML = this.value;
});
```